# How to get a string value from a sql table in visual basic

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, authentication

Basically I have a login system and want to add access rights. In order to do this I want my code to refer to my SQL database, return the value of access and then an if statement which would then direct the user according to their access rights. I believe the issue is when: If access = "Admin", as All I get now is the error message. I can't find out how to refer Admin to Admin in the SQL table.

```
  Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    'connection to the database
    Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim adaptor As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dataset As New DataSet
    Dim access As String


    'data location
    connection.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=CHRISTIAN;Initial Catalog=Complete;Integrated Security=True")
    'sql statement 
    command.CommandText = "SELECT Access_Level FROM [User] WHERE Username= '" & txtUsername.Text & "'AND Password='" & txtPassword.Text & ";'"
    connection.Open()
    command.Connection = connection
    adaptor.SelectCommand = command
    adaptor.Fill(dataset, "0")

    access = CType(command.ExecuteScalar(), String)

    Try
        If access = "Admin" Then
            MenuAdmin.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        ElseIf access = "User" Then
            Menu1.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MsgBox("Please try again, wrong username or password entered!")
            txtPassword.Clear()
            txtUsername.Clear()
            'txtUsername.Focus()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: have you actually got any sql code to communicate with your database or is that what you are asking for?

Comment: I have just updated it, sorry about that. The issue seems to be getting the value of 'access' from the table (from the select statement)

Answer (score 0):

If it is simply a case of connecting to the database to retrieve the value of a column called "access" you will need to look into ADO.NET. Its a rather big subject but there will be plenty of examples if you have a quick Google.

[Basic Microsoft ADO.Net example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using a dataset just to return this one field seems unnecessary if you aren't going to do anything else with the table.  Try something like

```
SqlDataReader reader=command.ExecuteReader();
string access="";

if(reader.HasRows){
   reader.Read();
   access=reader.IsDBNull(0) ? "" : reader.GetString(0);
 }
 else{
   //Handle unauthorised access
 }

reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();
```